# If my value stream has dev followed by test, how do I model a developer who writes tests first?

Tags: kanban

I am wondering how to construct a Kanban and generate meaningful cumulative flow diagrams in a scenario where steps are not required to be performed in the same order.

As an example, we might have columns "Development" followed by "Write-tests". But some developers write their tests first, in a "test-driven" or "behavior-driven" way.

I can make the workflow accommodate flow in either direction, but the resulting CFD will be skewed.

I could also merge the dev and test into a single column, but they are really different value-adds and the resulting cards would be larger than I want them to be.

Is there a Kanban way of handling such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Kanban’s fundamental principle is “Start from where you are” - that is model the flow that is currently being followed.

It sounds like you have a team that does not have a common process. As such, it makes sense to define the board with the various versions of the process as individual swim lanes - perhaps one per person, if each person follows a somewhat different process, or one swim lane per process variant. Perhaps the variants are for different work types - user stories vs. defects for example - and a swim lane for each with its own specific value stream may be justified.

Else, perhaps the team needs to discuss what the ideal process needs to be for everyone and then model that revised process.

As you said - in order to get a meaningful CFD - you have to resolve these questions and find flows that can be properly visualized - and over time - improved. Fundamentally, you and your team need to answer the question - why are you using/ implementing Kanban?

Comment: Maintaining different swim lanes is a bit of overkill, because for the most part the processes are the same. Just here, some agile purists want to do tdd which is fine, whereas others prefer to write code then tests. I just thought perhaps there's a Kanban way to model this without having to modify the value stream

Comment: I agree - the multiple swim lanes could definitely be an overhead.  On the other hand, it might be an interesting experiment to run 2 lanes - one for the purists and one for the general - and see over a period of time if one of them gives better results? Still, in a real work environment, that can be difficult to do.